# How to get property using function of a typed object in typescript

Tags: javascript, object, typescript-typings

Here is the interface:

```
interface {
    State?: string;
    Profession?: string;
}
```

Now I want to use the getProperty function to get the value based on key of object.

```
function getProperty<Context, K extends keyof Context>(obj: Context, key: K): Context[K] {

    return obj[key];
}

let key: string = 'State';
getProperty(context, key);
```

Now it returns the error

```
> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: index.ts:50:33 - error
> TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of
> type '"State" | "Profession"'.
```

How should i solve this?

Comment: Just don't use `key: string`?

Comment: This works however i've used an alternative as keyof Context could also make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `key:string` part

```
 let key:any = 'State'
```

Comment: `any` is not the type that should be used here

Answer (score 0):

`getProperty` function defined 2nd parameter `key` as `keyof Context`, so you need to define variable `key` in a similar way:

```js
let key: keyof IContext = 'State';
```

Assuming that `IContext` is the name of your interface. Full example would look like this:

```js
interface IContext {
    State?: string;
    Profession?: string;
}

function getProperty<Context, K extends keyof Context>(obj: Context, key: K): Context[K] {

    return obj[key];
}

let key: keyof IContext = 'State'; // should not be a string
const context: IContext = {}; // instance of IContext

getProperty(context, key);
```